# Else statement not working in Servlet

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me why the else statement in below code not working. I am beginner in java.

```
     try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
        String u = null;
        Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();

        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if ((cookie.getName()).equals("special")) {
                String name = cookie.getValue();
                if (!name.equals(u)) {
                    out.print("<b>Welcome to Profile</b>");
                    out.print("<br>Welcome, " + name);
                } else {
                    out.print(" LogIn First ");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: you havent assigned anything to `u`...

Comment: Can you define `not working` ?

Comment: @Reimeus Checking against null it seems.

Comment: if you're a beginner in java, then you should first learn java and get a bit of practice before working with servlets.

Comment: I am checking null actually, that means if there is a cookie named "special"  present and that is not null, than execute if and if there is no cookie (after i delete it with sign out method) than else shall work(which is not working).

Comment: @SURESH ATTA can anyone please answer and help a student learning?

Answer (score 1):

Your else is not sufficient because there are two else cases. First, the else to if the cookie name is equal to "special" and then Second, the else to if the value of the cookie named "special" is not null.  Rather than clog the code with two repetitious elses, here it would be best to set a boolean, something like as follows:

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
    String u = null;
    Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
    Boolean blnFoundSpecialCookieWithValue = false; //initialize to false
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) 
    {
        if ((cookie.getName()).equals("special")) 
        {
            String name = cookie.getValue();
            if (!name.equals(u)) 
            {
                blnFoundSpecialCookieWithValue = true; //set boolean
                out.print("<b>Welcome to Profile</b>");
                out.print("<br>Welcome, " + name);
            }
        }
    }
    //use boolean here to minimize number of else blocks needed
    //and not have to repeat the out.print()s
    if(!blnFoundSpecialCookieWithValue)
    {
        out.print(" LogIn First ");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `u` equals `null`, then you get the `String` name and it equals something, in the `if` statement, you check if `name` doens't equal `u`, it will always be true and the else will not be executed.

Comment: Dear name is not equals to null, which means, it consist a cookie in it so my if is working perfectly but when i delete the cookie that else should work, which isnt.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value of u is null.